# Is it ok to use Attribute::Handlers for implementing retry logic

Tags: perl

Is it ok to use `Attribute::Handlers` for implementing retry logic

I have almost 50+ subroutine like `verifyXXXX`. I need to implement the retry logic for all these subs. I want to write this retry logic where the sub is actually implemented. If the  return value of sub is false/undef then it will retry again.

subs will be called in regular way, so that the caller will not know about the retry logic, something like.

```
verify_am_i_doing_good()
    or die('sorry you are not doing as expected.');

verify_am_i_fine()
    or die ('sorry you are not find.');
```

:
:

the actual implementation of these functions is something like this in the package.

```
use Attribute::Handlers;

use constant RETRY_LIMIT => 4;
use constant RETRY_DELAY => 2;

sub verify_am_i_doing_good : __retry
{
    return 1 if ($x == $y);
    return;
}

sub __retry : ATTR(CODE) {
    my ($pkg, $sym, $code) = @_;

    my $name = *{ $sym }{NAME};
    no warnings 'redefine';

    *{ $sym } = sub
    {
        my $self = $_[0];
        my $result;

        logMsg (INFO, "Executing subroutine $name with retry limit " . RETRY_LIMIT);
        for (my $retryCount = 1; $retryCount <= RETRY_LIMIT; $retryCount++)
        {
            logMsg (INFO, "Executing subroutine $name with retry count $retryCount");
            my $result = $code->( @_ );
            if ($result)
            {
                logMsg (INFO, "Expected result observed in retry count $retryCount");
                return wantarray ? @$result : $result;
            }
            else
            {
                logMsg (INFO, "Expected result is NOT observed in retry count $retryCount");
                logMsg (INFO, "Retrying again by updating uixml");

                sleep RETRY_DELAY;
                $self->updateState();
            }
        }
        logMsg (WARN, "Failed to verify expected result for subroutine $name with retry limit " . RETRY_LIMIT);
        return;
    };
}
```

The reason to use Attribute::Handlers, inplace of Attribute::Attempts is that in the case of failure, I need to call another subroutine `updateState()` before retrying (re-executing) the subroutine.

I got this idea of writing the retry logic from following post http://www.perl.com/pub/2007/04/12/lightning-four.html

My main concern is that since I am using this __retry attribute for almost 50+ subs. Is it a good practice to do in this way or is there anything simple I can do?

You help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need attributes to do a sub wrapper. There was [`Memoize`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Memoize) long before there was [`Memoize::Attrs`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Memoize%3a%3aAttrs) (or [`Attribute::Memoize`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Attribute%3a%3aMemoize) for that matter). You can just take a look at how [`Memoize`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Memoize) handles it.

Quite recently, I was writing some Perl for functions called in another interface. All the arguments passed to the Perl function from this interface would be passed in a funky-but-universal format used by my division. Rather than deal with this everywhere, I wrote a logic wrapper like so

```
sub external (@) {
    my ( $subname, $code ) = @_;
    ...
    my $wrapped 
        = sub { 
            my $count = 5;
            while ( --$count and not my @results = &$code ) { 
                adjust_stuff();
            }
            return @results;
        };
    {   no strict 'refs'; # my special "no-block"
        *$subname = $wrapped;
    }
    return;
}
```

And used it like this (some people don't like this use of the "fat comma")

```
external something_I_want_to_do => sub {
    my @regular_old_perl_args = @_;
    ...
};
```

The prototype `(@)` helps a sub act as an operator and need not always be called with parenthesis.

But by all means if you *like* method attributes and it works and you can get it not to bite you, *use them*. But you don't have to. You should probably read up on the caveats though.

Comment: @Zaid see the caveats section on this page: http://www.perl.com/pub/2007/04/12/lightning-four.html. Sure it's not much more chancy that plenty of the stuff people do with Perl with AUTOLOAD and stuff. It's just the general problem of Perl magic when you get too many wizards casting spells over the same confined area. But then again functions which augment and process composed functions is a staple to functional programming.

Comment: @Zaid, Oh and there's an idea I forgot. The "core" attributes are `lvalue`, `method`, `locked` and `unique`. Two are deprecated and one `lvalue` has always been listed as "experimental" (and I haven't liked its limitations anyway). I usually end up lamenting that I wanted to use `lvalue`, but didn't. Oh, and I found this on perlmonks: "The :unique attribute has been made a no-op, since its current implementation was fundamentally flawed and not threadsafe."

Comment: @Axeman => you can get around some (but by no means all) of the quirks with `lvalue` attributes with the https://metacpan.org/module/Lvalue module that I wrote.  It aims to address the encapsulation violations that lvalue setters suffer from.  It doesn't do anything about providing list context support though, which would have to be fixed at the C level.  And I agree that it is just throwing more magic at the problem, but sometimes magic is ok.